# No me permite realizar consulta a Api con curl php

Tags: php, api, http, curl, peticion

estoy teniendo un problema en una consulta a una Api, ya que me esta devolviendo error 403 cuando realizo pruebas en Postman, me devuelve la respuesta correcta pero cuando lo realizo en código me devuelve el error, se solicito al proveedor de la Api para que nos dieran autorización en poder realizar consultas, se compartió la ip del servidor realizamos ping desde nuestro servidor para ver la conexión y todo funcionó, el caso es que raro, ya que realizamos consultas en Postman y responde correctamente pero ya en código nos da el error, es posible que se esté realizando mal la petición.

Se pidió autorización para realizar consultas desde el servidor.
Se realizó pruebas en postman y nos devuelve la respuesta correcta pero en codigó ya no funsiona
Se agregaron tokens de de autorización las cuales se agregaron en postman y funcionó correctamente pero ya en código, de echo agarramos el código que muestra postman para hacer la petición agregándola[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] tal cual está y tampoco funcionó

Respuesta que devuelve

403 Forbidden

## 403 Forbidden

Agrego el código

```
           $curl = curl_init();

           curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
              CURLOPT_URL => $url,
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
              CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
              CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
              CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
              CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
              CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
              CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
              CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "key: qjSfV?$^0,Mo?b$&Ne34deDE",
                "secret: gwyQg5LQ~K3?nQ7-1u4VqDe43",
              ),
            ));

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE)

            $response = curl_exec( $curl );
            $error = curl_exec( $curl );
```

Comment: Evita utilizar imágenes ya que no todos pueden verlas, agrega tu código con el formato correspondiente para que algún colaborador pueda replicarlo y ayudarte mejor, veo que eres nuevo, date una vuelta por el [tour] y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [ask].

Comment: Por favor, pon el código como texto pulsando en [edit] y no expongas tus credenciales reales, un usuario mal intencionado podría usarlas para acceder a esa API y usarla suplantando tu identidad, para obtener o modificar recursos o consultarla de forma abusiva generando facturación en caso que te tengas que pagar esa API por uso.

Comment: El error _forbidden_ indica que no tienes los permisos suficientes para acceder. Otro punto a considerar es que tanto en las imágenes como en el código se ven las _API Keys_ que estás usando, cuando estas deberían de ser privadas y confidenciales. Finalmente, no guardes las claves importantes dentro del código, eso significaría que cualquiera que pueda ver el código, podrá verlas (como en este caso), puedes usar variables de entorno que suelen ser más seguras.

Comment: Ok comprendo con las variables de entorno, pero tengo otra duda, realizando las pruebas en postman, me devuelve la respuesta exitosa con la información y estado 200 pero ya implementado en código siempre sigue devolviendo el 403 Forbidden

Comment: ¿Esa API no explica en su documentación cómo deben hacerse las peticiones vía cURL? Estás teniendo un problema de autorización y puede deberse a que no estarías poniendo las credenciales correctamente.

Comment: Fíjate que documentación no como tal no, mas que un .json de de prueba de postman compartieron, te comento que realizando pruebas, en la sección de headers agregue esta línea User-Agent y ya me dejo obtener la información     CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array(
                    "User-Agent: *"
                  ),

Comment: Juan, pon tu comentario como respuesta (pero expláyate mejor). Efectivamente hay muchas APIs públicas y privadas que rechazan peticiones sin User Agent  y con eso se sienten a buen recaudo de ataques DDOS  y de exfiltración. Pobres personas